# Конкретное число знаков после десятичного разделителя

Tags: java

Как записать число в экспоненциальную форму, чтобы осталось определенное количество символов после точки или подскажите где почитать можно информацию по этому вопросу.
Например нужно чтобы осталось десять знаков после точки: 0.0000000000000005 в 0.0000000005e+6.

И вообще возможно ли это? Или хотя бы как получить количество знаков после десятичной точки.

В указанной ниже ссылке такой информации нет.

Comment: 5e-14 (если в нулях не ошибся). В чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: [Форматирование чисел в Java](https://www.dev2qa.com/java-decimalformat-example/)